# Creating a placeholder file in multiple sub-directories at once

Tags: linux, file, command-line, directory

Using `find` and passing the results to `touch` we can create a file -placeholder/dummy- in multiple dirs:

`find . -type d -exec touch {}/someFile \;`

however the `find . -type d` also returns -and creates- a file in the current directory.

What would the command be to just create files in the sub dirs but not the current dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `-mindepth` option:

```
find -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir touch '{}'/someFile \;
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, though I had to move `-mindepth` before `-type` as it complained:

"find: warning: you have specified the global option -mindepth after the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e., -mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments."

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer with the correct order